# Angular2 RC1 multi level routerLink directive

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular, rc

still struggling with the new component router as of Angular2 RC.1.

My app's components are assembled in this manner:

```
Main
 - NavigationBarComponent
 - ContentComponent
   - UserComponent
     - UserSettingsComponent
     - UserNotificationComponent
   - CarComponent
     - CarDetailsComponent 
     - ...
```

The routing works fine for ContentComponent and all its child components. The issue is creating routes within the NavigationBarComponent, which is a permanently visible component offering some shortcuts to components.

If I assemble a link from the NavigationBarComponent to the UserSettingsComponent, the route should look like this:

```
/user/:id/settings
```

I managed to create such a link with this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/'+loggedInUser.id+'/settings']">
```

Concatening a link like this seems pretty ugly and wrong, though. I've tried a syntax like it was used in the deprecated routing of the beta versions

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/user/:id/settings',{'id':loggedInUser.id}]">
```

but the output looked like this:

```
/user/:id/settings;id=56edad04c506d7e7963edd48
```

I couldn't find any examples for this requirement in the docs or live examples. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', 'loggedInUser.id', 'settings']">
```

Comment: Wonderful. That's it. Thank you!